# SceneBuilder does not find ControlsFX library from MavenCentral

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, controlsfx

I have reproduced this in SceneBuilder 8.5.0 and 20.0.0 and can't get it to locate the ControlsFX library from maven central.  It seems the only way to get ControlsFX added into scene builder is to download the JAR file and add the JAR file manually from the file system.  Does anyone know why this happens or how to resolve it?  We use maven to manage this library for our project/build tools, and would like to also use maven to manage importing the library into SceneBuilder.

To reproduce:

1. Open Scene Builder
2. Open Library Manager
3. Click Search repositories
4. Enter controlsfx
5. Nothing is found
6. Click Cancel
7. Click manually add library
   from repository
8. GroupId: org.controlsfx
9. ArtifactId: controlsfx
10. No versions are found

I have confirmed that I can find other libraries from mavencentral.

Comment: On manually add, enter the group id and the artifact id as you have done. After that, hit enter. Now you should see version 12.0.0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did for the following version of SceneBuilder.

### SceneBuilder Version

[image]

### Searching Method

[image]

### Manual Method

You have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering the group ID and artifact ID.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  I am on the same version and when I search I get 'no items available'.  I have pressed enter after entering group id and artifact id and still nothing there as well.  I guess I'll have to take this problem to my local IT team.  Thank you.

Comment: I would uninstall Scenebuilder and reinstall it.

Comment: Offtopic: how do you create these animated gifs?

Comment: @jewelsea, I think it's opensource. https://www.screentogif.com/